# Crystal Report row should change when two different field is changed

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle10g

I am using crystal report 7 and the Oracle database. I have implemented the following SQL query in the crystal report:

```
SELECT ins.ins_name,ins.ins, SUBSTR(cardh.g_id,1,1), SUBSTR(cardh.g_id,2,2),
      SUBSTR(cardh.g_id,4,2), crdi.bn,
      sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'PO', 1, 0)) POCount,
      sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'CN', 1, 0)) CNCount
FROM crdh, crdi, ins
WHERE crdh.crd_st IN ('PO','CN') and crdi.bn in 
(select unique bn from crdh)and crdh.bn=crdi.bn and 
crdi.ins=ins.ins
GROUP BY ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name, cardh.g_id
ORDER BY ins.ins, crdi.bn;
```

Output of the above query:
[image]

To implement the above SQL query in Crystal Report I have made three groups on the cardh.g_id, crdi.bn, ins.ins in the same order. But Crystal report changes rows only when the cardh.g_id is changing. I want Crystal report should change rows only when the crdi.bn is also changing.

The current report is looking as follows:

[image]

The above report should be displayed as the output of the SQL query.

Screenshot for sort record expert:

[image]

Comment: Siva, Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you name the columns in your screenshot.. I am unable to understand which columns you are referring to... and next time if you post an message to anyone use `@siva` which will come to my inbox

Comment: @Siva, Thanks for your reply. I am adding name of the field in the output and report. But you need to check column 5 in from left in the output and report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok in this case what you need to do is to group the report as the combination of fieldds you require.

Create a formula `@Grouping` and write the combination something like:

```
ToText(cardh.g_id)+ToText(crdi.bn)+ToText(ins.ins)
```

Now use above formula to group the report.

Edit----------------------------------------

Go to `Record Sort Expert` and select the required field then select asc or desc as per your requirement.

Comment: I have added the column's name as header, I am trying your solution.

Comment: I have used your solution but it is not showing those records which was showing prior to your solution.

Comment: have you took the summary in group footer and place the fields in goup footer and check

Comment: if your output should be according to SQL output then don't group any fields just place the fields in design and run the report... because you have already applied grouping in query...

Comment: There is a field for serial number in the report. It shows the same serial number now. I have used count(ins.ins) in 'Field to Summarise'. How can I get the proper serial numbers. I did not add group clause in the Crystal report's SQL query.

Comment: I have solved the serial number issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I need to sort 'ins.ins' (INS) field in increasing order. I have modify the SQL query for 'order by' close but it does not saved in the query. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I think the problem is ToText(ins.ins)i the grouping formula

Comment: Take normal field not totext one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87377/discussion-between-amit-raj-and-siva).

Comment: Can you post preview screenshot and explain which field you want to sort

Comment: Yes, I can do in some time

Comment: I added preview screenshot. And you can see in the screenshot that there is a problem in INS (field1) field as 2 is coming after 19 and 3 is coming after 29.

Comment: Have you applied record sort as I explained

Comment: Yes I tried it. But did not make any difference as there is the 'grouping' formula is there and I am not able to remove it.

Comment: Even I can't change its order

Comment: Dont apply on grouping formula..apply sorting on individual field

Comment: I will get back to you on this tomorrow. There is some other complications also.

Comment: Can we look into this issue one more time today?

Comment: can we check this tomorrow in day time? I will ping u.

Comment: Sure but what is the issue

Comment: Ascending order for the ins.ins field

Comment: Can We discuss this now?

Comment: What is the problem with ascending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88755/discussion-between-amit-raj-and-siva).